# How do you get rid of those tick marks in command line Racket?

Tags: racket

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
$ racket
> (list 1 2 3)
'(1 2 3)
```

It's an annoyance very similar to constructor-style printing. What it's showing is basically that `(list 1 2 3)` evaluates to `(quote (1 2 3))`.

The `gracket` REPL doesn't do that (yet):

```
$ gracket -z
> (list 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
```

In DrRacket it's possible to get rid of the tick marks through a menu option pertaining to "output syntax", but command-line Racket has no menus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default Racket printer is controlled by the [`print-as-expression`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._print-as-expression%29%29) parameter. If you set this to `#f`, it will disable expression-style printing.

```
> (print-as-expression #f)
> (list 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
```

If you really do hate this behavior, you could add the `(print-as-expression #f)` line to your [init file](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28idx._%28gentag._287._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29) (`~/.racketrc` on Linux and OS X, `~/racketrc.rktl` on Windows), which will get loaded at startup.